# Stretching background images & colors to full width in the Skeleton CSS framework

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to create backgrounds (images or color) that stretch full with in the browser with the Skeleton CSS Grid? http://getskeleton.com - if you download Skeleton, you will see that the Container is a 12-column fluid grid with a max width of 960px. So if you want to create a header div and assign a class to it to change that background image, it will stay within the 960 container. It will not go full width of the browser. Take the header outside of the Container to go beyond 960 & you will break the grid. I would like for the content to stay within the 960 grid but the background is stretched to the edge of the browser - Any ideas?

Comment: Use css background-cover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, and without knowing your restrictions, I will suggest: Creating an extra element outside of the container class, which you can style accordingly. Rather than use a single full page container, you could use a container for each section of the site, `header>container | section>container | footer>container` etc...

```
CSS
      .header {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 25vh;
        background-color: blue; }
```

---

```
HTML
      <div class="header">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="twelve columns"></div>
          </div>   
        </div>
      </div>
```

This is the method used in the [Skeleton Demo](http://getskeleton.com/examples/landing/).
Take a look at the [Skeleton Demo source code](https://github.com/dhg/Skeleton/tree/gh-pages/examples/landing), to see how this method is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Using an absolute positioned element you can sort of jam a background into another element. Since the master container has `position: relative` you'll have to center it using `left: 50%;` and `transform`. `top: 0` will make it ignore the parent's padding but if you don't want the background to extend into the padding you'll have to add it to the element to match its parent container. `width: 100vw` will make it full width since `vw` units are relative to the viewport.

```
position: absolute;
width: 100vw;
left: 50%;
top: 0;
transform: translateX(-50%);
background: red;
height: 100%;
```